# How to add div dynamically inside of another div jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a content like this

`<div class="maindiv">
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
  </div>`

now I need to add div like this format

```
 <div class="maindiv">
<div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

how to do this in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var boxes = $(".maindiv > .box");

for (var i = 0, len = boxes.length; i < len; i += 2) {
  boxes.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<div></div>");
}
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/varoha/1/edit?js,output)